# Issues with displaying histograms in Matlab 2014b

Tags: matlab, histogram

I am plotting some simple histograms in Matlab 2014b, and having some issues with them displaying. The figure I am trying to produce has two histograms on the same figure, and I would like one to have filled bars, and the other one to be displayed in the `'stairs'` style over the top. I have managed to do them both as filled bars, but when I try and do the `'stairs'` one it doesn't display. To check it wasn't a problem with doing them both on the same figure, I tried to do the `'stairs'` one on its own and that didn't display either

Here is a MWE to show my problem:

```
r_num=normrnd(0,1,1000,1);
figure
histogram(r_num)
figure
histogram(r_num,'DisplayStyle','stairs')
```

The first histogram displays as expected, but the second one is just blank. The axes are there, but nothing in the axes. Does this happen to anyone else or is it just me? What can I do to fix it?

I also tried to do a histogram with the bar edges a different colour to the bars, and it didn't show the `edgecolor`, just the bar colour.

EDIT: I have now reported this to MathWorks as it appears to be a bug just for me (how lucky am I?!). After restarting Matlab, my PC and uninstalling & reinstalling, it still isn't working.

Comment: Mmmm It works for me

Comment: How odd! Are you using 2014b? I did restart Matlab to check it wasn't just that after posting, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, I am using Matlab 2014b freshly installed, and works like charm.

Comment: Ok! Something dodgy on my end then. Will try restarting the computer.

Comment: Hmm, it still isn't working. Might have to reinstall Matlab.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Can you post an image of your result for the `'stairs'` figure? I have just re-installed Matlab and it still fails to display a histogram. The normal histogram is fine.

Comment: I can if you want, but there is no mystery of it. Its just the outline of the histogram. I really just copypasted your piece of code.

Comment: @AnderBiguri Have you got any ideas why it isn't working on mine? If I copy and paste the exact code into my command window, it produces a light blue histogram in Figure 1, and just the axes in Figure 2.

Comment: Absolutely no idea. No clue. Sorry. It SHOULD just work.